# Why shared_timed_mutex is defined in c++14, but shared_mutex in c++17?

Tags: c++, c++14, std, c++17

C++11 introduced `std::mutex` and its extended version - `std::timed_mutex`.

However, in c++14 we have `std::shared_timed_mutex`, but its 'parent', the `std::shared_mutex` is going to be added in c++17.

Is there any reasonable explanation for that?

If I'm not going to use 'timed' functionality of `std::shared_timed_mutex`, is it going to be worse (slower, consuming more resources) than proposed `std::shared_mutex`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Shared mutex originally had timing in it, and was called `shared_mutex`.

An implementor (msvc iirc) noted they could implement it "cheaper" without timing.  In particular, `SRWLOCK` is an existing primitive on windows that is sufficient to implement shared mutex, but timed requires extra machinery.  (Via @t.c.).  (However, I believe it isn't just *easier* because already written, but also fundamentally more expensive, at least on x86/64 windows)

It was too late to add a new type to the standard, but not too late to rename it.

So it was renamed to `shared_timed_mutex`, and the untimed version added in next standard.

[Here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3891.htm) is at least one of the papers involved in the rename.

> We propose to rename shared_mutex to shared_timed_mutex:
>
> (a) for consistency with the other mutexes (fixing naming inconsistency);
>
> (b) to leave room for a shared_mutex which can be more efficient on some platforms than shared_timed_mutex.

Comment: @MartinBonner No, `CRITICAL_SECTION` isn't a shared mutex (aka reader/writer lock). `SRWLOCK` is the primitive.

Comment: Oh damn!  I got confused between "shared" and "recursive"!